# Changing Slider handle image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wanted to customize the JQueryUI slider but am not able to find any way to change the slider handle images. The JQuery Themeroller also does not seem to allow the change of handle images. Does somebody know how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**From the [jQuery UI docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#theming):**

> The jQuery UI Slider plugin uses the
>   jQuery UI CSS Framework to style its
>   look and feel, including colors and
>   background textures. We recommend
>   using the ThemeRoller tool to create
>   and download custom themes that are
>   easy to build and maintain.
>
> If a deeper level of customization is
>   needed, there are widget-specific
>   classes referenced within the
>   ui.slider.css stylesheet that can be
>   modified. These classes are highlighed
>   in bold below.

**In this particular case, you want to take a look at the element with classname *`ui-slider-handle`*.**

The default slider handle element has the following classnames applied to it:

- ui-slider-handle
- ui-state-default
- ui-corner-all

Take a look at the CSS corresponding to these classnames and you will most likely be able to edit everything you need.

Also, I suggest you install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). This Firefox plugin will make tasks like these a lot easier on you.

Comment: I can't find a reference to an image for the slider handle. Even worse, I cannot even find the handle image in /image folder! - currently I have absolutely no clues where the handles are coming from!

Comment: ok, finally found the width/length/corner properties making up the current handles. I am also able to change the background image. I think it should work now.

Comment: @Crimson - If you have time, it'd be great if you could you put the CSS that you used to alter the handle image in an answer to this question. I'm having the same issue but can't get any CSS working.

Answer (score 8):

```
#demo-frame > div.demo { 
    padding: 10px !important; 
    float: left;
}
.contentContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-state-default { 
    border: none; 
    width: 28px; 
    height: 82px; 
    background: transparent url(volume_bar/shattle.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-handle {
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: -41px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.ui-slider-range, .ui-widget-header, .ui-slider-range-min {
    background: none;
}
#slider-vertical, .ui-slider {
    border: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent url(volume_bar/track-bg.png) repeat-y 0 0;
}
```

someone asked in the comment section for sample css code so here's the one I used to change the handle and scrollbar background image to my own custom png image files. Make sure to insert the css AFTER the jquery ui css in the header section.