# How do I use a different image for each JQuery UI Slider handle

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm using a JQuery UI slider which has two handles (a.k.a *range* slider). I know how to [style the first handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207307/how-to-change-jquery-ui-slider-handle):

```
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {background: white url(https://stackoverflow.com/content/img/so/vote-arrow-down.png) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;}
```

But how do I style the second handle differently?

Using Firebug I can see Jquery does not uniquely identify each handle:

```
<div id="hourlyRateSlider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
 <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 26%; width: 46%;"/>
 <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 26%;"/>
 <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 72%;"/>
</div>
```

So I imagine I have to use either a CSS child selector which could be cross-browser problematic. Or I could use some JQuery trickery to add a CSS class to the second handle? Anyone done this in a neat way before?

Comment: @Tom - did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @karim79 - No, sorry - I never found out how to style each handle differently :-(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    handle = $('#slider A.ui-slider-handle');        
    handle.eq(0).addClass('first-handle');        
    handle.eq(1).addClass('second-handle');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
#hourlyRateSlider a:last-child {}
```

Comment: it should work on IE<9:

`.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle + .ui-slider-handle {}`