# jQuery UI Slider controller can replace other image? (can customize?)

Tags: jquery-ui, uislider

I have a simple question.

[image: Before]

See. that's a basically slider .

But I want to change it.

Like this.

[image: After]

is it possible ???? ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found it my self.

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle{
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background:url(../images/slider_grabber.png) no-repeat; overflow: hidden; 
    position:absolute;
    top: -10px;
    border-style:none; 
}
```

here is stackoverflow's other question page :

> [How to change Jquery UI Slider handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207307/how-to-change-jquery-ui-slider-handle)